# SSL certificate problem when using wptools

Tags: python, ssl, wikipedia-api

I am getting the following error message when using wptools on Jupyter on Udacity.

> error: (60, 'SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired')

This is the code.

```
import wptools
page = wptools.page('E.T._the_Extra-Terrestrial').get()
```

When I run that I get the following message.

```
en.wikipedia.org (query) E.T._the_Extra-Terrestrial
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-5bef4afd1ab8> in <module>()
----> 1 page = wptools.page('E.T._the_Extra-Terrestrial').get()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wptools/page.py in get(self, show, proxy, timeout)
    459             self.flags['defer_imageinfo'] = True
    460 
--> 461             self.get_query(False, proxy, timeout)
    462             self.get_parse(False, proxy, timeout)
    463 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wptools/page.py in get_query(self, show, proxy, timeout)
    574             raise ValueError("get_query needs title or pageid")
    575 
--> 576         self._get('query', show, proxy, timeout)
    577 
    578         return self

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wptools/core.py in _get(self, action, show, proxy, timeout)
     95         qstr = self._query(action, qobj)
     96         req = self._request(proxy, timeout)
---> 97         response = req.get(qstr, qobj.status)
     98 
     99         self.cache[action]['query'] = qstr

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wptools/request.py in get(self, url, status)
     74             print("Requests DISABLED", file=sys.stderr)
     75         else:
---> 76             return self.curl_perform(crl)
     77 
     78     def curl_perform(self, crl):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wptools/request.py in curl_perform(self, crl)
     82         bfr = BytesIO()
     83         crl.setopt(crl.WRITEFUNCTION, bfr.write)
---> 84         crl.perform()
     85         info = curl_info(crl)
     86         if info:

error: (60, 'SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired')
```

I am also unable to install wptools on Windows 10 to test it locally to check if it is something wrong with Udacity's Jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

## The issue

Kindly provide the error message you encountered when trying to download `wptools` on your Windows 10.

I had a similar issue with the Udacity workspace. I later found out that the issue is currently as of 14th June 2022, a technical issue on Udacity, I learnt it has been reported and the technical team has been informed.

## What I did

1. I downloaded the notebook (`.ipynb`) from the Udacity workspace
2. I uploaded the downloaded `.ipynb` file and opened it on my local machine (Windows).
3. I got an error also, but the error was because `wptools` is not pre-installed on Anaconda. So to do this I had to install it directly using pip as it is [here](https://pypi.org/project/wptools/).

on the first cell of your notebook, you can just use
`!pip install wptools`

4. With that installed you can remove the code `!pip install wptools` so you won't have to reinstall it anytime you run that cell.

That was how I did mine, and it worked fine on my Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

As wikipedia.org is signed by LetsEncrypt, and one of its CA certificates is expired:
https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

You need to remove the old DST root CA from your certificate store and add the ISRG root CA to your certificate store.

For Centos/Redhat, you can check your current CA in `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`, for Debian/Ubuntu, you can check your current CA with command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`

Answer (score 0):

I use Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda navigator.

[image]

I opened a new terminal to reinstall wptools on Anaconda environment

[wptools on github](https://github.com/siznax/wptools)

> $ pip install wptools

then it worked fine !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!pip install --upgrade certifi` to upgrade the certificates. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently took a Udacity class where I encountered this same error. Here's what worked for me:
Run `!pip install --upgrade certifi` in your Jupyter notebook (either Udacity workspace or on your local machine). Then run your wptools line again.